# Gmail API Push Notifications - PubSub to PHP/JS PWA?

Tags: php, gmail-api, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

so I'm having some trouble figuring out what the best way to do this is. My goal is to have push notifications from Gmail integrated into my webapp so my users dont have to refresh the page everytime to check the specified gmail label for unread messages.

The architecture currently is a PHP Backend that includes authentication for the user, as well as a service account to enable all users to "work out of" one of their inboxes.

Then theres a layer of JS for DOM Manipulation, etc.

Now I'm kind of confused as to how to best get these PubSub messages displayed in a Push manner.

I already have the clients creating a named subscription for themselves to the preexisting topic, if it doesn't yet exist, and calling watch() on it 1/day, as well as pulling messages. But pulling messages will only happen on reload, just like the current behavior. I want to have it push messages and the user receive a notification potentially.

Fyi theres a service worker as well in this application, I thought of maybe using that somehow? This is the first time dealing with anything like this so I'm a bit clueless as to the best way to go about this, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: My code works so far. The question is more one of architecture / planning. Do most people grab the pubsub messages on the backend in php, or in a worker somehow? Or should I spin up an extra node server for a specific route to accept the post requests from Google directly in JS?

Comment: Basically what I'm asking is what is usual way of going about receiving push pubsub requests with php based web apps

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Pub/Sub is not well suited to pushing to end user devices. You are likely better of using Firebase Cloud Messaging, which has [specific support for the web browser push api](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client).

I suggest a two stage architecture: first have Pub/Sub push to your server-side application, then have it push to clients via FCM:

```
+-----+ Pub/Sub +-----------+
|Gmail+-------->+PHP web app|
+-----+         +-----------+
                      |FCM
                   +--+--+
                   |  |  |
                   v  v  v
                +--+--+--+--+
                |Browser/PWA|
                +-----------+
```